# Nursing home spatial dataset for Spain

Tags: geospatial, medical, real-estate

I am undertaking a research piece on the spatial accessibility of nursing homes in Spain and am looking to locate an open-source dataset detailing all the nursing homes and their locations.

Many thanks

Comment: https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1Hkl and generally have a look on tagging: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nursing_home